# Subdomain In Addon Domain Is Not Working

Tags: apache, htaccess, subdomain

I added a new addon domain to my cPanel hosting. With the new added addon domain, I try to make some subdomain of it. But, the subdomain is not working like subfolder does.

This is my situation:

[image]

1. `mymaindomain.com` (the cPanel primary domain - OK)
2. `myaddondomain.com` (the new domain - OK)
3. `en.myaddondomain.com` (subdomain of the new domain - not working)
4. `myaddondomain.com/en` (subfolder of the new domain - OK)

What should I do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If your add on domain has not been set up to use nameservers, you will need to create a CNAME or A record in your DNS control panel (where you bought your domain name) to point your `en` subdomain to your server. How you do this varies between companies, but usually look something like this:

[image: CNAME subdomain example]

Here you can see that the `test` and `www` subdomains both point to the main domain. If your subdomain will be on the same server as your main domain, your `en` CNAME record can be set up the same way as this example to point to your main domain.

This is required because setting up a subdomain when you're managing your own DNS records requires two things:

1. A DNS record for your subdomain so that the DNS server knows which IP address to send visitors requesting `subdomain.example.com`
2. A server record for your subdomain so that the server knows which folder and files to serve when a visitor requests that subdomain.

It sounds like you have set up 2, but not 1.